# Raphael.js set movement with text "Raphael is undefined"

Tags: javascript, html, drag-and-drop, raphael

I have been struggling to implement drag and drop for a set in raphael.js.

I have managed to do so for sets that are made up of circles, using [this](http://jsbin.com/uxege4/7/edit) code on JSFiddle.

```
var r = Raphael(10, 50, 600, 600);    
var Intermediate = r.set();

var start = function () {
    // storing original coordinates
    this.ox = this.attr("cx");
    this.oy = this.attr("cy");
};

move = function (dx, dy) {
    // move will be called with dx and dy
    Intermediate.attr({cx: this.ox + dx, cy: this.oy + dy});
};

up = function () {};

Intermediate.drag(move, start, up);
```

However this does not work for sets made up from rectangles and text, because they do not have `cy` and `cx` properties. Replacing `cx` and `cy` with `x` and `y` respectively does not work as two objects will have different `x` and `y` values while concentric circles will have the same `cx` and `cy` values.

I found a solution, [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Alexis2000/mG2EL/), also on JSFiddle, which defines a new method in Raphael.st.

```
Raphael.st.draggable = function() {};
```

It then just enables the set to be draggable:

```
mySet.draggable();
```

Hoever when I try implement this solution in visual studio I get an error "0x800a1391 - JavaScript runtime error: 'Raphael' is undefined".

I don't understand why this is, I have added the Raphael script to my HTML.

Comment: Is it possible to put a fiddle up of the bit that isn't working, then someone can look at the specific undefined problem. As an aside, I think with dragging objects, its best to use transforms rather than changing attributes, as the attributes vary, but transforms are consistent. I think this is probably what the other solutions are using, but its worth just spending a short bit of time understanding basic transforms if you don't already. If you find the other solution too unweildy, you could also look at Snap.svg which is similar to Raphael, but maybe not as compatible with older browsers.

Comment: The problem is that it works in a fiddle. It just doesn't work in Visual Studio 2013. If I copy the code from the fiddle to VS2013, it gives the aforementioned error. But thanks for the hint on transforms, I will look into that!

Comment: Ah not sure then. I'm just going to add an extra comment on Snap.svg to highlight how simple an alternative could be if you are ok not needing old browser support, as Snap.svg is essentially based on Raphael (same author), but with proper support for groups. So you could do what you need to do in one line, like http://jsfiddle.net/RR27Y/1/ which will drag a group.

Comment: Thanks very much :) Ill have a look at that too! It seems very powerful.

Comment: Having had a slightly closer look at snap I am really impressed. Thanks again!